# Difference between continue and run

Tags: debugging, gdb

I just started learning GDB and was wondering what was the difference between continue and run. Don't they both do the same thing?

Comment: Did you try them out?

Comment: @alk `run` and `start` are not the same thing.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: yes, correct, what I wrote is confusing ...

Comment: What about the manual and the various tutorial online is unclear?

Answer (score 3):

> Don't they both do the same thing?

No. `continue` continues the execution of program that is currently being debugged, `run` *kills* current program (if any) and *starts* a new instance of it.

Comment: But `start` also restarts the program. How do then `start` and `run` differ?

Comment: @71GA Don't ask a new question in a comment, ask a _new_ question (it's free). Also reading the manual would help answer trivial questions like this one.